Docker build issues with CentOS: unable to resolve mirrorlist.centos.org in Dockerfile; CentOS Docker image deprecated
I have a Dockerfile that used to work, but now I am getting errors.
An example is:
FROM centos:7  

RUN yum install -y \  
    ca-certificates \  
    curl \  
    tree \  
;

When I run docker build -t image name . I am getting the following error:
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release7&arch=x86_64  
curl#6 - Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error" 
Can not find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64  

I changed the Dockerfile to FROM centos:8, but I get similar error
Error: failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Can not prepare mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for http://mirrorlist.centos.org  

The machine I am running this command is CentOS Stream release 8
Googling, I found this post, which mentions updating /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*.repo, but this file does not exist for me. What is this file, and do I need to create it?
I see this: DEPRECATED; The official build of CentOS.
Does it mean there is no CentOS Docker image anymore?

/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*.repo is not a single file, it is a wildcard pattern matching all files in /etc/yum.repos.d/ that begin with CentOS- and end with .repo.

@muru: yes I know, but there is no such file that starts with CentOS- How can I create one (if I should)?

So what files are present in that directory for you? Do any of them mention this problematic repo?

@muru: what should I grep for? mirrorlist?  The error says about resolving hostname of mirrorlist.centos.org

mirrorlist.centos.org doesn't exist anymore.
The link you posted mentions:

All tags of this image are EOL (June 30, 2024⁠ / docker-library/official-images#17094⁠, although the last meaningful update was November 16, 2020

In fact, CentOS has reached its End Of Life in 2021 (CentOS 8) and 2024 (CentOS 7).  It is not supported anymore, so there aren't Docker images officially supported.
You should switch to another RHEL-compatible distro; the closer to CentOS is Rocky Linux, and its latest release is 9.

Suggestion: They should try using rockylinux:9 instead of centos:7.
